# VB.NET process plain text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to use [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) to process a very large plain text file (2 GB). It is a database and has a field delimiter of `SOH` and a record delimiter of `STX`.

I want to separate the fields and records of the file.

I would normally read each line of a text file and then use the split function to separate out the fields. I can't use this approach as there isn't always a delimiter on every line.

Is there any way to read a file until `STX` is found (rather than one line at a time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Read until string 'foo'" in .NET, you need to open a `FileStream` and read chunks with [`FileStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) into a temporary buffer and scan that buffer for your tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into the TextFieldParser class to see if it's up to the task:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

If it's not, I'd then try the free FileHelpers library:

http://www.filehelpers.com/

If neither of those can do the job, then you're down to good ol' fashioned filestream reading with buffers, as Albin mentions.